# matlab function to return an image

Tags: matlab, function, image-processing

I have created a function in matlab which returns an image:

```
 function [BW3] =lineAnalysis( BW1, O)

BW2 = double(BW1 > 0);
BW3 = BW2(2:end, :); % <-- REMOVE 1st LINE (ARTIFACT)!


if O==0; % 1 for left 
  BW3 = fliplr(BW3); % <-- FLIP IT HERE!
end 
BW3_orig = BW3; % <-- SAVE ORIGINAL VERSION

% STEP 1
n = 10; t = 0.9; 
c = 0:(n - 1);
j0 = 1;
while mean(mean(BW3(1 + c, j0 + c))) < t 
  j0 = j0 + 1;
end 

% STEP 2
i0 = 1;
while mean(mean(BW3(i0 + c, 1 + c))) < t 
  i0 = i0 + 1;
end 

% STEP 3
a = (1 - j0) / (i0 - 1);
b = j0 - a;
for i = 1:i0
   for j = 1:round(a * i + b)
      BW3(i, j) = 0;
   end
end

% STEP 4
w = 20; 
for i = 1:round(i0 - w / a)
   for j = max(1, round(a * i + b + 1)):round(a * i + b + w)
      BW3(i, j) = 1; 
   end
end

% PLOT RESULT
[BW3] = size(BW3);

[nr, nc] = size(BW3);
  % figure

subplot(122), imagesc(BW3), colormap(gray)
axis equal off, axis([1, nc, 1, nr]), title('Corrected')
```

This works perfectly.

However I would like to return the result in my main program instead of executing the line 
    imshow(BW3);

within the function.

I have tried doing this:

```
 [BW3]=lineAnalysis(P, O);
```

I then tried to show the image by doing

```
 imshow(BW3);
```

However this doesnt work when I show the image like this. It simply diplays one black image and one white image.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this??

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is near the end of your code:

```
function [BW3] =lineAnalysis( BW1, O)

  %% your calculations here

  % PLOT RESULT
  [BW3] = size(BW3);

  imshow(BW3);
```

In the line `[BW3] = size(BW3);` you are replacing the image with a 2 element vector that has the numbers of rows and columns of your image.

Comment: This did not work either! It just showed a white image. I will add the code of my function to the question incase I am going wrong somewehre

Comment: @user1853871 yes, you better paste your code and exact error. Your current explanation is not enough but I'm going to bet it has to do with changing your image from logical or uint8 into double.

Comment: @user1853871 it can't work. If it works, then the code you pasted on the question is not the same you are running.

Comment: sorry, I;m being silly, I have it working now, i did not read your answer correctly.